# Argument must be a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been stuck adding brackets upon brackets to this monstrosity but no matter what I do it's either I'm missing a bracket or **Argument must be a range**, and it's not helping that it won't show me where it's wanting a range from in the following equation:

```
=IF(OR(AND((ROW(VLOOKUP(Calculator!A2,Pokemon!A1:I898,1,FALSE))>=793),(ROW(VLOOKUP(Calculator!A2,Pokemon!A1:I898,1,FALSE))<=799)),AND((ROW(VLOOKUP(Calculator!A2,Pokemon!A1:I898,1,FALSE))>=803),(ROW(VLOOKUP(Calculator!A2,Pokemon!A1:I898,1,FALSE))<=806))),5,0.1)
```

Basically what it's supposed to do is reference another one of my sheets, grab the row ID and determine if it's a special group. If it is it applies the 5 if not 0.1, any help is welcome as I don't want to be stuck here forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is in your ROW(....) function.

The argument you are using is:

```
=ROW(VLOOKUP(Calculator!A2,Pokemon!A1:I898,1,FALSE))
```

With my test data, this gives the "argument must be a range" error.
If you shared your sheet, we could confirm this, or you can focus on the result of the VLOOKUP, and see whether that returns a range as a string, eg AB17.  If it just returns a number, or some other value, you'll get that error.

Let us know if that is it.

**Comment:**

If you format your formula, it can sometimes help when working through the logic  when debugging.  Perhaps something like the following:

```
=IF(OR(
       AND(
           (ROW(VLOOKUP(Calculator!A2,Pokemon!A1:I898,1,FALSE))>=793),
           (ROW(VLOOKUP(Calculator!A2,Pokemon!A1:I898,1,FALSE))<=799)),
       AND(
           (ROW(VLOOKUP(Calculator!A2,Pokemon!A1:I898,1,FALSE))>=803),
           (ROW(VLOOKUP(Calculator!A2,Pokemon!A1:I898,1,FALSE))<=806))
      ),
   5,
   0.1)
```

Comment: Just focused on the result of the VLOOKUP and it turns out I forget it does return a string, might you know any alternatives that would give what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Actually found a less complex solution to do what I wanted without needed to search a cell, thanks for the help anyways though. I'll accept the answer since I believe you get reputation for that.

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow.  Glad you have a better design approach for your spreadsheet issue.

Comment: Hi @MilesPerHour ! Could you please share with the community the approach you ended up using as an answer to this post so that other users with similar questions can easily find it? Thanks ! :D